# EmacsをJava用IDEとして使い倒せるパッケージはありますか?

Tags: emacs

ここ数ヶ月Android Studioのお世話になっており、よくできているなと感心しています。これまでEmacsが長かったのですが、Android Studio/IntelliJと同等のことができるほどには使い込んでいません。

Android Studioでは以下の操作をよくしています。これをEmacsで実現できるようなIDEパッケージはありますか? ひとまずJavaが対象ですが、多言語対応でも可です。

1. 検索: ソースツリー内のファイルをファイル名から検索して開く
2. 検索: ソースツリー内のファイルをファイルの内容から検索して開く
3. 検索: メソッドや変数の定義に飛ぶ
4. 検索: メソッドや変数、クラスを使っている行をソースツリー内から検索する
5. リファクタリング: メソッドや変数、クラス名を任意のスコープ内で (メソッド内のみ、クラス内のみなど) 一気に変更する
6. リファクタリング: その他リファクタリング全般 (メソッド切り出しなど)
7. コード編集支援: クラス名やスコープ内の変数などから変数名を自動補完する
8. コード編集支援: カーソルがある行をif文やtry/catch文などで囲う
9. コード編集支援: カーソルがあるメソッドの引数名や型、返り値を表示する
10. コード編集支援: 静的コード解析で見つかった問題を修正する (インポート文を自動挿入するなど)

更新: 範囲が広すぎたため、質問の方向をピボットして、全部を実現できるようなソリューションがないかを問う質問にしました。

Comment: 個別のテーマとして、質問を作成したらどうでしょうか。
これだとドレか1つの質問を選ぶことができない回答が付き、
あとから読む人にとって有用ではありません。

Comment: つっこみ、待ってました！「条件が具体的だが沢山あるおすすめ系質問はどうなのか」として後でメタに投稿します。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. 検索: ソースツリー内のファイルをファイル名から検索して開く
> 2. 検索: ソースツリー内のファイルをファイルの内容から検索して開く
> 3. 検索: メソッドや変数の定義に飛ぶ
> 4. 検索: メソッドや変数、クラスを使っている行をソースツリー内から検索する

helm https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm というパッケージが検索というか絞り込みの操作全般をまかなう定番です。ソースツリー内のファイル検索はさまざまなやり方があると思いますが helm と組み合わせるなら helm-ag https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-ag がいいと思います。

キー操作については、 helm のインストール作業の一環として自分で好みのキーバインドを定義することになりますので、短くて打ちやすい（覚えやすい）キーバインドを使えます。

> 5. リファクタリング: メソッドや変数、クラス名を適切なスコープ内で一気に変更する

「適切なスコープ」がよくわかりませんが、リージョンを選択して M-x query-replace でも（原始的ですが）一括置換は可能です。が、

> 6. リファクタリング: その他リファクタリング全般 (メソッド切り出しなど)

こういうのは Emacs Lisp パッケージで実現するのは難しいのではないかと思います（探せばあるのかもしれませんが...）

> 7. コード編集支援: クラス名やスコープ内の変数などから変数名を自動補完する

これは限定的ではありますが標準機能の動的略語展開 (dabbrev-expand) で補完できます。変数名を途中まで打って M-/ を押してみてください。

> 8. コード編集支援: カーソルがある行をif文やtry/catch文などで囲う

私は使ったことがないのですが yasnippet https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet などを駆使すれば似たようなことが実現できるかもしれません。

> 9. コード編集支援: カーソルがあるメソッドの引数名や型、返り値を表示する
> 10. コード編集支援: 静的コード解析で見つかった問題を修正する (インポート文を自動挿入するなど)

5, 6　のリファクタリングと同様、静的なコード解析まで行う高機能な Emacs Lisp は（探せばあるのかもしれませんが）思い当たるものがありません。過去に Ruby のコード解析を行う RSense http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/index.ja.html というツールを使ったことがありますが、 RSense 自体は Java で書かれていました（付属の Emacs Lisp パッケージのインタフェースを通じて Emacs から利用する）

私は Eclipse や Android Studio/IntelliJ などの IDE に習熟していないので比較したわけではないですが、静的コード解析や自動リファクタリングのような機能は Emacs のカスタマイズをするよりも素直に IDE の機能を利用したほうが良いと思います。

Comment: 1-4: その後helm + projectileを導入していたので、さらにagも入れました。速いですね。 5: たしかに。これを機会に expand-region を使うようにしてみます。 8: `yas-wrap-around-region` の設定でできそうです。([今はちょっとバグがあるようですが](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet/issues/523)。) 静的コード解析やリファクタリングは質問の範囲として広すぎでもありますね。 (個々の言語ごとに分けて質問した方がいい) この質問としては解決済みにします

Answer (score 4):

Android Studio/IntelliJとあるので、Javaを前提としますが、一番メジャーなのはmalabar-modeでしょうか。
導入はかなり面倒です。

CEDETの拡張でJDEEというのがありますが、開発停止しており・・・と思ってましたが再開されたようです。
こちらを試してみてもいいかもしれません。

http://mikio.github.io/article/2012/12/23_emacsjdeejava.html

Answer (score 4):

## 適切なスコープだけ編集

適切なスコープだけ編集したいのであれば、narrowing系コマンドを駆使すればいいと思います。

まず最初にnarrowing系コマンドでパニックにならないように、解除方法である `C-x n w` (`M-x widen`)を覚えてください。このコマンドが最重要です。

narrowingとはバッファの特定領域だけを編集範囲にするものです。表示もその特定範囲だけになります。基本はリージョンを選択して`C-x n n` (`M-x narrow-to-region`)です。そうすると選択範囲以外は消えてしまいます。表示上消えただけです。narrowingを解除すると現れるので大丈夫です。

このnarrowingの状態ですと表示されている領域しか編集対象になりません。置換なんかもこの範囲内です。編集を終了したら前述の`C-x n w`で元に戻してください。

ちなみに初めてnarrowing系コマンドを使うときは「本当に大丈夫か?」みたいなことをEmacsが聞いて来ます。これはこのコマンドを知らないとパニックを起こすためです。narrowing系コマンドは他に、

- `narrow-to-defun` (カーソルのある位置の関数・メソッド定義)
- `narrow-to-page` (`^L`で挟まれた領域。elispはこれでページを分けたりしているようです)

があります。カーソルのある位置のクラス定義全体を編集範囲にしたいときは

1. `C-M-u`を何度か押してクラス定義の先頭にカーソルを持って行く
2. `C-M-space C-x n n`でnarrowing
3. 心ゆくまで編集し
4. `C-x n w`でnarrowing解除

という手順になります。`C-M-u` (`M-x backward-up-list`)はブロックを遡る (押すたびに一つ上のレベルのブロックにカーソルが移動する)、`C-M-space`(`M-x mark-sexp`) はブロックをマークするというもので覚えておくと便利かと思います。

ただし、`narrow-to-defun`や`mark-sexp`や`backward-up-list`はメジャーモードが対応していないと使えないかもしれません。lisp-modeとruby-modeで使っていますのでこれらモードでは動きます。

もうひとつ、リファクタリングにはmultiple-cursorsパッケージが有用かと思います。

## メソッドの切り出し

これは`C-M-k`(`M-x kill-sexp`)と前述の`C-M-u`を駆使しましょう。`C-M-u`でメソッドの先頭に持って行って、`C-M-k`です。

あるいは`M-x mark-defun`の後に`C-w`でもよいかと思います。

Answer (score 3):

CEDET http://cedet.sourceforge.net/
はどうでしょうか。
1.~4.は実現できると思います。
（残りもいくつかは実現できると思います）

Answer (score 2):

> コード編集支援: クラス名やスコープ内の変数などから変数名を自動補完する

Auto complete mode(http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/index.ja.html) はいかがでしょうか?
GNU Global(http://www.gnu.org/software/global/) のタグを情報源に補完できるので、完璧とはいえませんが、そこそこ快適にコーディングできると思います。